# Persistent view with UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to build an app with layout similar to Apple Music - a tab bar navigation with a persistent view, accessible from everywhere in the app. The view can be expanded to take up the whole screen or minimised with a static height of 80. The UI is built in a storyboard with a normal `UITabBarController`. Here's a first draft: [image: 1]]

This is how I've build it:

```
class TabbarViewController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        embedLiveFeedbackController()
    }

    private func embedLiveFeedbackController() {
        guard let feedbackController = UIStoryboard(name: "LiveFeedback", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as? LiveFeedbackViewController else { return }

        feedbackController.stateDelegate = self
        addChildViewController(feedbackController)
        view.addSubview(feedbackController.view)

        feedbackController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        feedbackController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        feedbackController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        feedbackController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBar.topAnchor).isActive = true

        liveFeedbackTopConstraint = feedbackController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
        liveFeedbackHeightConstraint = feedbackController.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: Constants.minimizedHeight)

        liveFeedbackHeightConstraint?.isActive = true
        liveFeedbackTopConstraint?.isActive = false

    }
}
```

The problem I have is that the content of the view controllers goes behind the persistent view and is not completely visible. One of the things I've tried is to constraint the view controllers to the top of the persistent view:

```
private func constraintViewControllers() {
    guard let vcs = viewControllers else { return }
    guard let topAnchor = liveFeedbackTopAnchor else { return } // a reference to the top anchor of the persistent view

    for viewController in vcs {
        viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Of course, I get the following error:

```
Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600000864640 "UILayoutContainerView:0x7fc813f0ea60.bottom"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x60400047b980 "UIView:0x7fc813f08af0.bottom"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
```

Any suggestions how to go about implementing this?

Comment: Every time I ask a question like this here on SO, I get similar responses (next to nothing). I'm beginning to believe that scroll views' content insets and automatically adjusting them is not widely understood. And those that do understand it are not usually willing to answer. I'm curious to see if you get any knowledgable feedback.

Comment: If I had more time to explore this at the moment, I would look more into `UIViewController.additionalSafeAreaInsets` and `UIScrollView.adjustedContentInset`. You might be able to adjust your `UITabController`'s `additionalSafeAreaInsets` (or that of its child view controllers) during `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (I'm not entirely sure that will work, but might get you on the right track). And for pre-iOS11, I'd probably look into some sort of `UILayoutGuide`-based solution.

Comment: Sorry I can't be much more help than that. But I hope that might be enough to get you on the right track. And if you do figure out a good solution, I'd love to see it, and I'm sure others would benefit from the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion, I tested it and worked fine

create a main viewController and put 2 view inside it (as in picture) :

[image]

```
-startViewController 
--containerView (your app root viewController/tabBarController goes here)
--persistentView
```

**in startViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var tabController : TabController!

@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var persistentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var persistentBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tabController = TabController.initFromStoryBord()
    
    self.addChild(tabController)
    tabController.view.frame = containerView.bounds
    containerView.addSubview(tabController.view)
    tabController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    
   
    persistantBottomConstraint.constant = tabController.tabBar.frame.height
}
}
```

**and then a class for TabBarController:**

make sure to set Stroyboard ID for tabController

```
class TabController : UITabBarController {
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    static func initFromStoryBord() -> TabController {
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabController") as! TabController
        return vc
    }
}
```